# Python pool.apply_async() blocks or is stuck when task as input arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm creating a machine learning pipeline from raw market data to final forecasting.

Since I want to gather, preprocess, and analyze multiple assets in parallel, there is a need for "asynchronous" processing.

It seems that apply_sync stops and does not execute the function when the function was input parameters:

**This does not work:**

```
pool.apply_async(self.generateFeatureListRealtime,args=(apiObject,apiObject2,apiObject3,alpacaPollPrice,header,sampleSize))
```

**This works (no input args):**

```
pool.apply_async(self.generateFeatureListRealtime)
```

However, I need to supply & prefer passing in input parameters. **Below are relevant snippets the rest of my code:**

```
**Main.py (only relevant parts):**


#GLD
stock = Asset(global_vals,"GLD","ETF",datetime.now)
alpacaPollPrice.addSubscribedSymbols(stock)
#SH
stock2 = Asset(global_vals, "GLL", "ETF", datetime.now)
alpacaPollPrice.addSubscribedSymbols(stock2)
#SPY
stock3 = Asset(global_vals,"SPY","ETF",datetime.now)
alpacaPollPrice.addSubscribedSymbols(stock3)

#start polling alpacaPollPrice.continuePolling(), uses a executor and recieves current price data from APIs (works as expected) in the background. 

alpacaPollPrice.continuePolling()
alpacaPollPrice.asyncProcess()

#THE PROBLEM - is asyncGenerateFeatureListRealtime()
stock.asyncGenerateFeatureListRealtime(new_fin_action, None, alpacaAction, alpacaPollPrice, True,GlobalValues.SAMPLE_SIZE)
stock2.asyncGenerateFeatureListRealtime(new_fin_action,None,alpacaAction,alpacaPollPrice,True,GlobalValues.SAMPLE_SIZE)
stock3.asyncGenerateFeatureListRealtime(new_fin_action,None,alpacaAction,alpacaPollPrice,True,GlobalValues.SAMPLE_SIZE)
```

**Asset.py:**

```
class Asset:
        #This a very large class with functions that generate 100+ features , therefore only the code that is relevant to question is included
        def __init__(self,global_vals:GlobalValues,symbol,asset_type,currentDateTime:datetime):
            super().__init__()
            self.symbol = symbol
            self.asset_type = asset_type
            self.currentDateTime = currentDateTime
            self._realtimeFeatures = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.headers)
            self.global_vals = global_vals
            #required directory for realtime CSV output
            self.global_vals.makeDirectory(self.global_vals.REALTIME_PROCESS_RESULT_DIRECTORY)
            pool : Pool = None
    
        #***THE PROBLEM IS HERE! apply_async(self.generateFeatureListRealtime(),...) blocks and does NOT run in its own process!
           def asyncGenerateFeatureListRealtime(self,apiObject:ApiAction,apiObject2:ApiAction,apiObject3:ApiAction,alpacaPollPrice,header,sampleSize):
               try:
                  self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
                  if self.pool is not None:
                  self.pool.apply_async(self.generateFeatureListRealtime(apiObject, apiObject2, apiObject3, alpacaPollPrice, header,sampleSize),args=(apiObject, apiObject2, apiObject3, alpacaPollPrice, header,sampleSize),callback=None)
               except Exception as e:
                  print(e)
    
    
          def generateFeatureListRealtime(self, apiObject: ApiAction, apiObject2: ApiAction, apiObject3: ApiAction,alpacaPollPrice, header, sampleSize):
            print("Class generateFeatureListRealtime() line , sampleSize\n:", sampleSize)
            ini_time_for_now = 0
            row_counter = 0
            row = []
            timestamp = ""
            symbol = self.getSymbol()
            asset_type = self.getType()
            current_price_of_day_feature = self.global_vals.DEFAULT_MISSING_NUMERIC_VALUE
            high_price_of_day_feature = self.global_vals.DEFAULT_MISSING_NUMERIC_VALUE
            low_price_of_day_feature =  self.global_vals.DEFAULT_MISSING_NUMERIC_VALUE
            #100 other variables & features are ommitted from the post 
    
            index = 0
            #while data gathering is true
            while self.global_vals.CONTINUE_GETTING_DATA:
                print("Asset, generateFeatureListRealtime(), self.global_vals.CONTINUE_GETTING_DATA:", 
                self.global_vals.CONTINUE_GETTING_DATA)
                while index < sampleSize:
                    print("Asset, generateFeatureListRealtime(), rowCounter:", index)
                    try:
                        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                        # new row
                        self._realtimeFeatures.iloc[index, 0] = timestamp  # 'timestamp'
                        self._realtimeFeatures.iloc[index, 1] = symbol
                        self._realtimeFeatures.iloc[index, 2] = asset_type
                        print("Current Price:", alpacaPollPrice.getLastCurrentPrice(self.symbol))
                        current_price_of_day_feature = 
                        alpacaPollPrice.getLastCurrentPrice(self.symbol)
                        print("High Price:", alpacaPollPrice.getLastHighPrice(self.symbol))
                        high_price_of_day_feature = alpacaPollPrice.getLastHighPrice(self.symbol)
                        print("Low Price:", alpacaPollPrice.getLastLowPrice(self.symbol))
                        #etc...
                        index = index + 1
                        print("line 1689 DEBUG, Asset, generateFeatureListRealtime(), rowCounter:", 
                        index)
    
                        if self.global_vals.DEBUG:
                            print("DEBUG, Asset, generateFeatureListRealtime(), rowCounter:", index)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("Exception, Class Asset generateFeatureListRealtime(),Exception", e)
                        index = index + 1
                        continue
                #inside 1st while
                self.write_csv_to_file()
    
    
        #data_file_iteration is used to increment the file name
        data_file_iteration = 0
        #function used to output data to CSV file
        def write_csv_to_file(self):
            # write data to disk
            try:
                index = 0
                # output latest data
                string_yyy_ydd_mm = datetime.today().strftime(self.global_vals.DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_mm_dd)
                path = self.getRealTimeCSVPath(self.global_vals.FILE_TYPE_PROCESSED, string_yyy_ydd_mm, self.data_file_iteration)
                self._realtimeFeatures.to_csv(path_or_buf=path, sep=",", index=False)
                # reset data for the next iteration
                self._realtimeFeatures = None
                self._realtimeFeatures = self._realtimeFeatures = DataFrame(columns=self.headers, index=range(self.global_vals.SAMPLE_SIZE))
                self.data_file_iteration= self.data_file_iteration + 1
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception, Class Asset generateFeatureListRealtime(),Exception", e)
```

Therefore each **Asset (SPY,GLL,etc..)** is its own object and calls it's own `asyncGenerateFeatureListRealtime()` , which in turn calls `generateFeatureListRealtime()` via `pool.apply_async()`.

However the call `generateFeatureListRealtime` **blocks or is not asychronous when I supply input arguments**.

Appreciated!!!

Comment: First argument for "apply_async" should be "self.generateFeatureListRealtime" without appended parentheses. Your code calls the function in the main thread because of the parentheses.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, your suggestion was helpful, i corrected the 'apply_async' signature to 'pool.apply_async(self.generateFeatureListRealtime,args=(apiObject,apiObject2,apiObject3,alpacaPollPrice,header,sampleSize))'. however function is no longer called nothing happens. I actually removed all the code in function and left a few print() statements as a final effort. It seems `pool.apply_async`  does not execute. The pool is stuck. There are no errors or exceptions.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I got the code to run when there are no inputa arguments. However even dummy functions with input args dont run.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Have you carefully moved all of your one-time stuff into an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block?  Remember that the mutliprocessing code starts a brand-new interpreter which has to re-import your modules from the beginning.

Comment: You know that you just pass those arguments as a tuple as the second parameter to `apply_async`, right?